# Auto mouse click 25 seconds after mouse stops moving

Tags: mouse

I already have hover click and the other assistive technologies turned off but there is still a click initiated 25 seconds after mouse motion stops. I can't find any way to turn it off.  I can't concentrate to write when my cursor is jumping around the screen by itself. I'm going to try another distro to see if they have forced the same kind of nonsense on users. If they have I will have to start writing my blog on paper. How stupid is that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by disabling hover click.
But until I found solution, I had 2 ways to stop it:

1. Turning mouse upside-down when not in use.
2. Running "mousetweaks -s" from the terminal. I had to do it after each restart.